# como hacer una colision de dos cuadrados?

Tags: java, matemáticas

hice este codigo, para que colisionen 2 cuadrados pasados por parametro. intento hacer la colision basandome con los atributos de los cuadrados

```
public boolean VerificarColisionCuadradoCuadrado(Cuadrado obj1, Cuadrado obj2) {
        if (obj1.x + obj1.w <= obj2.x) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.y + obj1.h <= obj2.y) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.x > obj2.x + obj2.w) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.y > obj2.y + obj2.h) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

siendo cuadrado:

```
public class Cuadrado {

public int w, h;
public int x;
public int y;
public int color;

public void dibujarCuadrado(Graphics g, int posX, int posY, int base, int altura,int color) {
    Line.drawline(g, posX, posY, base + posX, posY, color);
    Line.drawline(g, base + posX, posY, base + posX, altura + posY,color);
    Line.drawline(g, base + posX, altura + posY, posX, altura + posY,color);
    Line.drawline(g, posX, altura + posY, posX, posY, color);
    this.w=base;
    this.h=altura;
    this.x=posX;
    this.y=posY;
    this.color=color;
}
```

no encuentro el error, no colisionan

el error pienso que esta en la funcion

> VerificarColisionCuadradoCuadrado

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @sstan no se a que te refieres

Comment: Me refiero a que deberías ayudarnos a reproducir tu problema. Esto se logra incluyendo un código que sea un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. El enlace explica como se logra eso.

Comment: @sstan que parte no entiendes? para mi esta re entendible

Comment: No es asunto de entender, sino de poder reproducir el error.

Comment: @rn3w que no colisionan. Quiere saber si dos cuadrados están separados, o si están "juntos" (bien rozan aristas o uno está dentro del otro; si intersecan).

Comment: @Peregring-lk los cuadrados estan separados y tienen que rozar cualquier lado para ser considerado interseccion

Comment: @rn3w Bueno, la definición matemática no la conozco, pero vamos, un "roze" de aristas, sea intersección o no, sería una intersección con volumen 0, un *corner case* que he preferido separarlo de la intersección propia.

Comment: Veo que lo haces en Java. Podes usar el método intersects(creo que se llamaba así) de la clase Rectangle. Devuelve un boolean si un rectángulo está dentro de otro.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo en tu código es que trabajas sin tener en cuenta cierto margen de error a la hora de la colision. Deberías tener en cuenta esto a la hora de trabajar con problemas reales de simulacion.

Comment: es un problema real

Answer (score 0):

solo era problema de codigo

```
public boolean VerificarColisionCuadradoCuadrado(Cuadrado obj1, Cuadrado obj2) {
        if (obj1.x + obj1.w < obj2.x) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.y + obj1.h < obj2.y) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.x > obj2.x + obj2.w) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj1.y > obj2.y + obj2.h) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

elimine la igualdad de las 2 primeras condiciones y ahora funciona !!!

Comment: No pierdas el tiempo con mi otra respuesta. Tu versión está perfecta y más eficiente, con tus restricciones de que `w` y `h` son positivos y los cuadrados paralelos al suelo. Fundamentalmente compruebas que `obj2` comience en el área complementaria de `obj1` para decir que no colisionan. Funciona incluso en el caso en donde un cuadrado está contenido en otro.

Comment: @Peregring-lk creo que el tuyo funciona igual de bien, aunque no lo testee muy bien

Answer (score 0):

No se para que lo estás usando exactamente pero lo mismo te sirve la librería Box2D. Tiene un montón de funcionalidades y te puede ahorrar mucho trabajo.

http://box2d.org